# Mac address pattern angular4 input

Tags: regex

I am trying Mac address pattern in an angular4 input

```
pattern="/\w/,/\w/,'\:',/\w/,/\w/,'\:',/\w/, /\w/,'\:',/\w/,/\w/,'\:',/\w/,/\w/,'\:',/\w/,/\w/"
```

I need mac addresses in the format MM:MM:MM:SS:SS:SS, where M/S should be alphanumeric.

Please help

Comment: I used pattern="([0-9A-F]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-F]{2}) but this match digits only

Comment: Please add some input text and expected output, and - IMPORTANT - add the details about your programming environment.